# Listar pasta de arquivos web

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Estou tentando lista uma pasta de arquivos, não estou conseguindo,

o erro fala que o **directoryinfo** não suporta URL.

```
DirectoryInfo directoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo("http://127.0.0.1");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileList = directoryinfo.GetFiles();
```

Comment: E o que mais além do já informado você deseja saber?

Comment: @bigown era so isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por HTTP não tem como fazer isso desta forma. Na verdade vai ter que existir API e acesso remoto que lhe permita fazer por HTTP.

Se quiser só pegar os dados na rede e puder ser por qualquer protocolo aí pode fazer acesso direto, como faria direto no Windows, assim:

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\127.0.0.1");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/RemoteGetFiles.cs).

Claro que também precisa ter permissão de acesso à máquina, o que é certo no `localhost` e provavelmente precisará especificar o diretório para funcionar.

Usei o [`EnumerateFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_) porque tem melhor desempenho.